# In standard SQL, is it possible to join to only distinct matches somehow?

Tags: sql

I have a table of "child" objects that each have a foreign key to a "parent" in a different table.

I would like to get a field from each "parent" that has "children" — but only once per parent. If that field is unique, I could do this via:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.slug 
FROM parent 
INNER JOIN child 
   ON parent.id = parent_id;
```

But what if the field I want is *not* unique? How can I *join* on distinct ids, rather than filtering after the join? Something like:

```
-- this does not actually work
SELECT parent.first_name 
FROM parent 
INNER JOIN child 
   ON DISTINCT parent.id = parent_id;
```

I want a single row for each parent that has one or more children. If a "John Smith" has five children and "John Doe" has nine children, I should get two "John" rows (one for each parent).

I suppose I could do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.id, parent.first_name 
FROM parent 
INNER JOIN child 
   ON parent.id = parent_id;
```

…but is this the most efficient way, even if each "parent" row could have thousands of "child" rows in practice?

Comment: Why join at all; it's what's causing the duplication right? Simply use exists `Select * from parent where exists (Select * from child where parent.id = child.parent_ID)`

Comment: As you can see there are many way to do it. The most important thing to keep it efficient is have the proper index for `parent.id` and `child.parent_id`

Answer (score 5):

Why not this?

```
SELECT parent.first_name
FROM parent
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM child
    WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a derived table.  It isn't necessary here, but it's a good tool to be aware of:

```
SELECT p.parent_id, p.first_name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
      FROM child) c
JOIN parent p on p.parent_id = c.parent_id
```

Side note: there is a good chance your RDBMS will be smart enough to handle this query in the exact same way as your normal join/distinct.

Comment: I think you mean `SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM child`, From parent they are already unique

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do want more field from the child table, try this:

```
      SELECT p.id, p.first_name --,child.child_name,...
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT parent.id, parent.name
            from parent) p INNER JOIN child 
        ON p.id = parent_id;
```

Else, the first answer is good enough.